# The issue with registering two repositories in DryIoc

Tags: c#, dryioc

previously I registered the repository as follows:

```
container.Register(

                typeof(IAsyncRepository<>),
                 typeof(AsyncRepository<>),

                reuse: Reuse.Scoped,

                 made: Parameters.Of.Details((request, p) =>
                     p.ParameterType
                      .GetGenericDefinitionOrNull() == typeof(IDeletingStrategy<>)
                && (!p.ParameterType
                      .GetGenericParamsAndArgs()
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                     ?.IsAssignableTo<IUndeletable>() ?? false) // ToDo check logic here

                      ? ServiceDetails.Of(value: null)
                      : null)); // the default injection behavior
```

Here I define which deletion strategy to assign to the model's repository. Now the task has become more complicated, I have added a second repository AsyncCompileRepository: IAsyncRepository". The base repository needs to be registered with the key RepositoryType.Base, and compile with the key RepositoryType.Compile. Will the following registration work correctly:

```
 container.Register(
    
                    typeof(IAsyncRepository<>),
                     typeof(AsyncRepository<>),
    
                    reuse: Reuse.Scoped,
                    serviceKey: RepositoryType.Base,
    
                     made: Parameters.Of.Details((request, p) =>
                         p.ParameterType
                          .GetGenericDefinitionOrNull() == typeof(IDeletingStrategy<>)
                    && (!p.ParameterType
                          .GetGenericParamsAndArgs()
                          .FirstOrDefault()
                         ?.IsAssignableTo<IUndeletable>() ?? false) // ToDo check logic here
    
                          ? ServiceDetails.Of(value: null)
                          : null)); // the default injection behavior
                
container.Register(
    
                    typeof(IAsyncRepository<>),
                     typeof(AsyncCompileRepository<>),
    
                    reuse: Reuse.Scoped,
    
                    serviceKey: RepositoryType.Compile,
    
                     made: Parameters.Of.Details((request, p) =>
                         p.ParameterType
                          .GetGenericDefinitionOrNull() == typeof(IDeletingStrategy<>)
                    && (!p.ParameterType
                          .GetGenericParamsAndArgs()
                          .FirstOrDefault()
                         ?.IsAssignableTo<IUndeletable>() ?? false) // ToDo check logic here
    
                          ? ServiceDetails.Of(value: null)
                          : null)); // the default injection behavior
```

And how to register the second repository so that the first one is always used by default, and the second one is only used if we explicitly specify the serviceKey attribute, while also correctly taking the deletion strategy?

Comment: Please re-format your code samples, it is very hard to read.